# In pandas dataframe, looking to split letters from the name column, assign values to each letter based on dictionary value, then

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

In pandas dataframe, looking to split letters from the name column, assign values to each letter based on dictionary value, then...then add them up and put the sum into a new column.

#create numerology dictionaries

ORDINAL = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, ...}

df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\Akachi LLC\OneDrive\Desktop\PYTHON\gem.xlsx")

#seperate letters into individual columns first?

string = df['Name'].to_string()

letter = [x for x in string]

`your text `print(string)

I ACTUALLY DONT KNOW YET HOW TO ASSIGN DICTIONARY VALUES TO EACH LETTER. I'm a newbie. Forgive me.

IDEALLY, If I have a list of names:

Larry Cohen

Brad Bittlesby

Eric Crank

Reggie Oxenfried

I'd like to assign a value to each letter:

L = 12

a = 1

r = 18

r = 18

y = 25

..... along with C o h e n - looking to add those values up 12+1+18+18+25+... and append it to a new column on the same row...

SO - its not mostly code its just how it shows up....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, I would write a function that does your calculation for just a single name, and then apply that function to every name in your dataframe's `Name` column.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Larry Cohen", "Brad Bittlesby", "Eric Crank", "Reggie Oxenfried"]})
ORDINAL = dict(zip("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", range(1, 53)))

def calculate_name_sum(name):
    chars = list(name)
    nums = [ORDINAL[char] for char in chars if char in ORDINAL]
    return sum(nums)

df["name_sum"] = df["Name"].apply(calculate_name_sum)
```

Output:

```
               Name  name_sum
0       Larry Cohen       171
1    Brad Bittlesby       191
2        Eric Crank       134
3  Reggie Oxenfried       203
```